# Unexplained sort operation in execution plan

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following query on a database with 7.5 million records:

```
UPDATE TestTable
SET TestCol='1234', TestCol2='1234', TestCol3='1234', Anonymised=1
WHERE [Date] >= '25 June 2016' 
AND [Date] <= '25 August 2016'
```

For some reason the execution plan includes a sort operation on the primary key.

[image]
[image]

I wouldn't expect it to have to sort the primary key given that there is already a clustered index on that column.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and what I might do to avoid the sort operation?

Edit:

Table creation script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestCol] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TestCol2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TestCol3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Anonymised] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: If you do range queries on the `Date` column often, you may want to consider clustering on the `Date` column instead of the `Id` column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your plan is using a nonclustered index keyed first on, presumably, `Date` to find values that qualify for your `WHERE` clause.

In order to optimize IO access of the clustered index update, data coming out of that index access operation is sorted to match key order of the PK/CX.

As an aside, [you shouldn't be updating that many rows in one go](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/).